# Use same SSL certificate for Tomcat on port 80 and Apache on 8080

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have got a SSL certificate for domain "www.example.com" and I have installed this certificate in tomcat server which runs on port 80 which runs fine. Now my requirement is to run php code in https  since my Apache is running on 8080 how do I make https:// work on port 8080. Is it even possible? I tried installing same certificate in Apache (Editing SSL.conf file to point to my certificate.). I even converted tomcat keystore to apache key file. But I think I need mod_ssl which is not installed in my server and I am not even able to install it (Reconfigure Apache with mod_ssl).

To summarize my questions :

1. Is it possible to install SSL certificate on server running on port 8080.
2. Is it possible to use same certificate generated from tomcat keystore in Apache
3. What is the easiest way to do this?
4. How to reconfigure Apache with mod_ssl if installing SSL certificates requires that. (This maybe a dumb question -> Under which folder do I run *./configure --enable-ssl*... type of command)

My basic requirement is to run both PHP and JSP codes through https.

Comment: It's not clear how you've installed Apache Httpd, but most distributions provide `mod_ssl` with it (perhaps it's simply not enabled). In addition, you should consider configuring port 443 with HTTPS, not 80 (which is the default port for HTTP), and perhaps 8443 instead of 8080.

Comment: Apache was installed by my hosting provider and i confirmed with them that mod_ssl is not installed. My Tomcat is running on 80 but my https is at port 443. My problem is that my jsp files can be accessed using https. But I also want to run php files through https. How can I do that? I access my php files through **http**://www.example.com:8080. I want **https**://www.example.com/ to also work

Answer (score 4):

The simpler way to do this is to use Apache as the front-end, and use its ProxyPass capabilities (the opposite of your setup).

Have Apache run on port 80 and 443 (SSL), and Proxy requests for specific websites and/or URLs to Tomcat running on 127.0.0.1:8080.

It's simpler because to set this up in Apache, all you need is to add one line...

```
ProxyPass /foo http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo
```

So when a request comes in for https://www.example.com/foo, Apache get's /foo from Tomcat, and transparently passes back to you... And everything is SSLed as far as the user is concerned.

If you don't want to do this...

> 1) Is it possible to install SSL certificate on server running on port 8080.

Yes. Port numbers are not hardcoded to anything. Just enable SSL in that Tomcat Connector.

> 2) Is it possible to use same certificate generated from tomcat keystore in Apache.

It should be. Certificates are domain-based. They don't care about what type of server uses them... BUT they do need to be in the right format. You might need to re-format the key and cert.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have many app running live on Tomcat, So I am a bit scared to change Tomcats port. But based on your approach I googled for Tomcat equivalent of ProxyPass and found some resources. I'll give them a try and see if anything works out.

Comment: I was in a similar situation.. I had the Apache server setup at 80 and tomcat at 8080.. The option ProxyPass /foo http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo
did the trick and saved my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

just follow the steps, it is pretty easy :)
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04